# paste clipboard into shiny app?

Tags: r, input, shiny, clipboard, fileinputstream

Here is an example that I could browse a file as input, but instead of browsing I would like to paste the data from clipboard. Any idea ?

```
if (interactive()) {
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
accept = c(
"text/csv",
"text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
".csv")
),
tags$hr(),
checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
),
mainPanel(
tableOutput("contents")
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
output$contents <- renderTable({
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile))
return(NULL)
read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
})

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `textAreaInput()` for user to paste his data and then do whatever you need to with it. See the doc page [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textAreaInput.html).

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textAreaInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary", width = "1000px"),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```